# Tkinter: processing button clicks using lambda / eval

Tags: python, tkinter

The following is the simplest code required to illustrate my question:

```
def function_one():
    pass
def function_two():
    pass

def button_clicked(function_name_as_string):
    # do stuff common to all button clicks
    # here...
    # then respond to specific button click by converting the
    # supplied function name string into an actual function which runs.
    eval(function_name_as_string + "()") 

button_one = Button(root,text="Run Function One",
                    command=lambda: button_clicked("function_one"))

button_two = Button(root,text="Run Function Two",
                    command=lambda: button_clicked("function_two"))
```

This is an attempt to make my tkinter code as compact as possible. Here, there are multiple buttons. But rather than write a function to handle each button click, I wanted a single function to handle all button clicks. In particular, that's because there are some operations I want to execute in response to any button click, before responding to the specific button click. At the same time, I wanted to eliminate any lengthy if/elif statement in the `button_clicked` function, which would be required for the function to know which button had been clicked, and take appropriate action.

In my solution above, when a button is clicked, the `command` keyword calls my `button_clicked` function, but also uses `lambda` to send the name of the function I want to run in response to the button click. The `button_clicked` function executes the code common to all button clicks, then uses `eval` to convert the supplied function name (passed as a string) into an actual function that now runs.

So the `button_clicked` function is not aware of which button was clicked. Rather, it is aware of what function ought to run in response to the specific button click. And this code runs perfectly.

I have never used lambda before, nor have I used eval. I came across both during a long search. But because both are new to me, I am a bit wary. My question is simply this: is the above approach correct and sound? Or are there hidden pitfalls that I may not be aware of? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't think of any hidden pitfalls, but careful with SQL-injection-like attacks.

Comment: Don't pass the function name; jus pass the function itself: `command=lambda: button_clicked(function_one)`. Just as `Button` takes a callback function, so too will `button_clicked`.

Comment: The pitfall is that using `eval` makes the code harder to understand.

Comment: Thanks - not sure I understand the solution offered above by @chepner. If I pass function_one using lambda, as he suggests, won't the button_clicked function see that as a string, rather than a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue it's better to pass the actual function than the function name as a string. `eval` rarely adds any value over other solutions, and mostly just makes the code harder to understand.

```
def function_one():
    pass
def function_two():
    pass

def button_clicked(function):
    # do stuff common to all button clicks
    # here...
    # then respond to specific button click by calling 
    # the specified function
    function()

button_one = Button(root,text="Run Function One",
                    command=lambda: button_clicked(function_one))

button_two = Button(root,text="Run Function Two",
                    command=lambda: button_clicked(function_two))
```

Comment: Okay...my question above cleared up. If I pass function_one without quote marks, it will be recognized as a function rather than a string, and I won't need to use eval. I didn't know I had that option. Many thanks for these responses.

Comment: `def` statements are really a combination of a function definition and an assignment. `def function_one():...` produces an object of type `function`, then binds that object to the name `function_one`. Like any other value, this can be assigned to other names, passed as function arguments, etc.